# I declared method but its showing error while calling

Tags: android

I call a method Submit() in onCreate portion which is initialized next to onCreate. "invalid method declaration,return type required" error is showing at calling spot. See my code and help me to solve it. Thnaks in advance

```
btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data = "("+
                    "\"name\":" + "\"" + ET_name.getText().toString() + 
 ")";
  }
        Submit(data);
 });



 private void Submit(String data) {
    final String saveData = data;
    String URL="http://172.0.0.1:8000/invoices/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error on `onClick` curly braces , you should call `Submit` inside them not out them.

```
btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Submit(data);
    }
});
```